# The program crashes sometimes and works perfectly fine sometimes. A variable array is declared and its size changes 2 times in the program

Tags: c++, arrays

The program crashes sometimes and works perfectly fine sometimes. A variable array is declared and its size changes 2 times in the program. I am using visual studio. It is in c++.

This is the code in c++:

```
int sz;                           //size of array
std::cin >> sz;                        //getting size
int* arr = new int[sz];           //declaring variable array.
for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
{
    arr[i] = i;                   //assigning values to all members of array
    std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;       //printing the array
}
std::cin >> sz;                        //size changes again
for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
{
    arr[i] = i;                   //assigning new values
    std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;       //printing the array
}
```

Comment: `//size changes again` no it doesn't. you are just reading in a new value for `sz`, this doesn't resize `arr`

Comment: ^ If the number you enter second is bigger than the first, you get Undefined Behaviour (and it's perfectly valid for UB to "sometimes crash, sometimes work perfectly fine")

Comment: Just use a [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). See also [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: *A variable array is declared* -- A modern C++ program should not be doing this: `int* arr = new int[sz];`, and instead should be using `std::vector<int> arr(sz);`.

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
std::cin >> sz;                        //size changes again
```

The comment is not really correct. The variable representing the size *is* changed, but the array `arr` is not changed. So indexing into any position greater than or equal to the old size will invoke undefined behavior. This means the program may work sometimes, and not others.

To resize the `arr` array, after the above line you need to do:

```
delete [] arr;
arr = new int[sz];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resize arr you must delete the old one and allocate a  new one

```
delete[] arr;
arr = new int [sz];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate a vector with new you should delete it after you no longer need it, and don't reuse it arbitrarily so your code would be better as:

```
int sz;                           //size of array
{
  std::cin >> sz;                        //getting size
  int* arr = new int[sz];           //declaring variable array.
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
  {
      arr[i] = i;                   //assigning values to all members of array
      std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;       //printing the array
  }
  delete [] arr; // << Delete old one here, missing in original
}
{
  std::cin >> sz;                        //size changes again
  int* arr = new int[sz]; 
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
  {
      arr[i] = i;                   //assigning new values
      std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;       //printing the array
  }
  delete [] arr; // <<--- Here as well, missing in original - less important, but leads to memory leak.
}
```

or just use `std::vector<int> arr(sz);` and you can ignore the delete. If you absolute need to re-use the array use `arr.resize(sz);`

Comment: You show a correct solution, but you don't explain what is wrong in the original code.

Comment: I marked the two missing delete above to make that clearer. Remember that it's two delete missing in the original code, not 
*one*.

Comment: In there original code there is only **one** `delete[]` missing because there is only one `new int[sz]`. And the answer still does not explain what the problem in the original code is.

Comment: There is *one new* and *two deletes* missing in the original code, and the problem with the original code is that an array is re-used needlessly. Consistently having new and delete for each separate use of an array is the best way to avoid that - and using a smaller scope helps enforcing that.